# Does bitly API support CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, url-shortener

I saw in their documentation that CORS is supported. But my attempts to make request from JavaScript have no success.

Requesting this URL:

https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?longUrl=https://google.com/&access_token=token&domain=bit.ly&format=json&languageCode=en-US

I receive standard error :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://google.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**UPD:** bitly documentation - http://dev.bitly.com/cors.html

Comment: You might want to link to the documentation you are talking about.

Comment: If their documentation doesn't match reality, then you should take it up with their technical support team.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still having this issue. The reason this happen is because the option (preflight) response from bitly doesn't include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

to get around this I used XMLHttpRequest which doesn't send preflight.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?longUrl=https://google.com/&access_token=token'
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
     if(xhr.status===200) {
         console.log(xhr.responseText)
     } else {
         console.log(xhr)
     }
   }
};
xhr.send();
```

It is actually mentioned in bitlly's [documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/cors.html)