# Successful JQuery ajax response being handled by the error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I have the following snippet:

```
function unshortBitlyLink (link, callback) {
    var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/expand?access_token=' + API_TOKENS.BITLY + '&shortUrl=' + link.href;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

            var url = data.data.expand[0].long_url;
            setLinkText(link, url);
            if (callback) callback(url);
        },
        error: function (response, message) {
            debugger;

            if (callback) callback(link.href, response);
        }
    });
}
```

(geting an api token requires registration on [bitly.com](https://bitly.com/a/sign_up); sorry about that),
which succeeds as seen on the Chrome dev tools:

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_txt": "OK",
    "data": {
        "expand": [{
            /*"short_url": (removed as stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post a bit.ly link),*/
            "long_url": "http://good.barkpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/stuck-shiba-inu.jpg",
            "user_hash": "2iRcKet",
            "global_hash": "2iRgc9a"
        }]
    }
}
```

Response headers:

[image: Response headers]

However, the error handler is executed instead of the success one. The object received there looks like this:

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

Any ideas?

---

Update: I had my console output filtered and showing only console.log(). When deselected, I saw this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/expand?access_token={token}&shortUrl={bitlyUrl}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Funny thing is I have another get ajax request, this one to the YouTube api, and that one isn't complaining.
```

Comment: This seems that your ajax call is ok but, there is problem with your token.

Comment: Try to hit your url from browser directly with parameters
 / args

Comment: I don't think I would get the proper response if the token wasn't so as well.
Entering the URL directly on the direction bar returns the same JSON posted above as response.
@NitinDhomse FYI

Comment: what does the browser's network tab and/or console tell you was the HTTP response code? Just because you got a 200/OK in the returned JSON doesn't mean anything to $.ajax. It will choose to run the error function if the _actual_ http response code is not 200. Check that, and see if there's an error message or non-200 response.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What I get from the dev tools network tab was already published on the original issue description, @ADyson.

Comment: Here, have a [screenshot](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/peqfPBoH7.png)

Comment: @JesúsCruz your data and screenshot show the actual body of the response - the content - but not the real http headers/response from the bitly server.  Click the Headers tab to see them.

Comment: @JesúsCruz Don't Panic is right, that's just the content from the server. It could be anything. The ajax call does _not_ read that content when deciding whether to run the "success" or "error" functions. It reads the actual HTTP code given in the response header. You can see this in the browser's network tab if you drill down into the ajax call.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that; always glad to learn. Here are the [response headers](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/fGCKP1Md.png) for the ajax call. When entering the url directly on the address bar I get [different headers](http://pasteboard.co/piNKJNbLD.png).

Comment: Added additional error I had missed. @ADyson FYI

Comment: @Don'tPanic FYI

Comment: @JesúsCruz You should encode your url `var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/expand?access_token=' + API_TOKENS.BITLY + '&shortUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(link.href);`

Comment: bitly links only use characters that don't require encoding so i find it kind of redundant. Tried it, nevertheless, with no noticeable change. @AndrésAndrade FYI

Comment: Looks like CORS issue to me. The response headers does not have required cors headers set. Though in their website, https://dev.bitly.com/cors.html , they say that CORS in enabled.

Comment: Could be an issue on their side, @Developer? The snippet they have on the link you posted triggers the same CORS error I get with mine. Weirdest thing is I used this in the past, same api version, and it used to work.

Comment: I kind of think the same. Do they have any technical support to verify this? Even there is an SO question in the same lines posted long back, but that aint answered yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141578/does-bitly-api-support-cors

Comment: It might have worked in the past when browsers were not strict about CORS. Or did you had luck in modern browsers as well?

Comment: "there is an SO question in the same lines posted long back". It seems like the guy left the token placeholder instead of replacing it.
Back to my code, it didn't stop working until not much ago. I though I was the one responsible as I frequently refactor the code where this is located.
In any case, I will clone this issue on their discussion group and see what I can get. Thank you, everyone, for your support so far.

Comment: @JesúsCruz - May be you can try once after disabling the CORS in your browser

Comment: That way it works but it sadly wouldn't suffice as a solution as I'm not the only one using this, @Developer.

Comment: No you shouldn't be using that way, just wanna make sure that its Cors issue